# Is it insecure to sign the value 0 with ElGamal?

Tags: attack, elgamal-signature

Is it insecure to sign the plaintext 0 with ElGamal signature algorithm? Can this leak the private key, give the possibility to forge other signatures or does provide any other attack vector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it insecure to sign the plaintext 0 with ElGamal signature algorithm?

It is insecure to verify the plaintext that hashes to 0 with the ElGamal signature algorithm, because anyone can generate such a signature with only the public key.

The validation requirement is:

$$g^{H(m)} = pk^r r^s$$

(where $g$ is the curve generator, $H(m)$ is the hash of the message, $pk$ is the public key, and $r, s$ are values provided in the signature).

If $H(m) = 0$, then this reduces to $1 = pk^r r^s$.  If we generate a signature with $r = pk$, and $s = (p-1)-pk$ (where $p$ is the prime modulus), then it is easy to see that the relation is satisfied, and that we have successfully generated a signature with only the public key.

Comment: If I may add to the excellent answer, because of the expected preimage resistance of any decent hash function $H$, it's effectively impossible to find a message that hashes to 0.

Comment: This was a question from university. In the meantime we got the solution. The attack is not possible because x must be a group element of Zp*. 0 is never an element in Zp*.

Comment: @PCFX: if $x$ refers to what I call $H(m)$, that doesn't make sense - El Gamal doesn't use $x$ as a group element of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$

Comment: @poncho: Yes we use x instead of H(m) sorry. You are right, we use this book (p. 271) and I also don't see any restriction on x or H(m) there: https://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~mbarbulescu/cripto/Understanding%20Cryptography%20by%20Christof%20Paar%20.pdf Well you could e.g. not calculate anything in the s equation where H(m)^-1 is needed if H(m) is not element of Zp*. But I guess this applies to multiple other H(m) as well that are not part of Zp*. I guess nobody can restrict me which messages or hashes I try to sign with ElGamal.

Comment: @poncho: Is it a requirement that x or H(m) must be a group member of Zp*?

Comment: @PCFX: no; El Gamal signature performs operations on it as a member of $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ (addition, using it as an exponent); 0 is a member of that ring...

Comment: @poncho: Can you explain why ElGamal signature uses an additive group in that case? I always thought ElGamal only operates on a multiplicative prime group?

Comment: @PCFX: as part of the process, the signer computes $(H(m) - priv \cdot r) \cdot k^{-1}$.  Those operations are done in $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$